# AJAX and PDO problems

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, pdo

OK so I have been for 2 days trying to do this but for some reason, doesn't matter in what way I do it, it doesn't work (I tried different way with json_encode and then taking care of creating the elements with javascript, I've tried to echo the  in the php itself, I've tried to return it, nothing really works)

What I'm trying to do is use AJAX to ask the server for a specific script (right now test.php) and then return the `<option>`'s so I can populate a `<select>`, so I'm trying to populate a comboBox, what seems to be happening is that the AJAX response is coming out empty, I tried to output the result and it was outputting an empty value. Can anyone please help me, I'm really desperate at this point, it should have been easy, I've spent hours on stack overflow trying to find the problem, I've debugged the code to the best of my ability, I've read everything relevant in the jquery documentation. well anyways my setting my suffering aside, here's the code:

comboStaging.php :

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="testForm">
    <select name="states" id="states">
        <?php

        $odb = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database', 'root', '');
        $query = "SELECT id, name FROM `database`.pt_state";
        $data = $odb->prepare($query);
        $data->execute();

        while ($row = $data->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            echo '<option value="' . $row['id'] . '">' . $row['name'] . '</option>';
            //print_r($row);
        }
        ?>
    </select>
    <select name="cities" id="cities">

    </select>


</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        console.warn("test");

        function loadFirst() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "test.php",
                cache: false,
                data: "id=1",
                dataType: "html",
                success: function (data) {
                    console.warn("test2")
                    console.warn(data);
                }
            });

        }

        console.warn("test3");
        loadFirst();
    });

    $("#states").change(function () {
        var ID = document.getElementById("states").valueOf().value;

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "test.php",
            cache: false,
            data: "id=" + ID,
            success: function (r) {
                document.getElementById("cities").innerHTML = r;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Test.php:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html');
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/resources/scripts/php/conn/dal.php";


$stmt = $DB_con->prepare('SELECT id, name FROM `database`.pt_city WHERE state_id=:state');
$stmt->bindParam(':state', $_GET['ID']);
$stmt->execute();

if($stmt->rowCount() > 0 ) {
    while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $test = $test . '<option value="' . $row['id'] . '"id="optionTest">' . $row['name'] . '</option>';
    }
}
return $test;
?>
```

Dev console:
[image: dev console]

Comment: Instead of `return $test;` use `echo $test;` and see what is there in developers console.

Comment: And why `$("#states").change` is __not__ in `document.ready` block?

Comment: @u_mulder I've tried it, but I'm reruning it now, I'll post an image with the dev console

Comment: @u_mulder Does it need to be there? I was keeping it outside because I only want it to run once the other combo changes.

Comment: @u_mulder also, originally I had the script tag inside the <head>, I switched it around to see if anything would change

Comment: By the way `ID` and `id` are __different__ indexes in php.

Comment: Turn on error reporting in your PHP if it's off. That will tell you if `$test` isn't defined, i.e. if `$stmt->rowCount() < 0`. Also, initialize `$test` to a value which will tell you if your database query returned no rows, or use an `else` clause to find this out

Comment: @u_mulder I feel so dumb... 2 days just to find out it was a problem with capitalization, I didn't even realize I made that huge stupid mistake. Sometimes you just need some help from someone that hasn't been messing with the project. Well anyways post the answer if you want and I'll accept it ;)

Comment: PHP's error reporting would have also been of help.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Aye true, now its no longer needed but I activated it for the future ;)

Comment: @MrSanchez It's sort of like a mechanic who (can) fix their own vehicle. When it works like a top, they can then put away their tools ;-) *Cheers*

Comment: @ MrSanchez if @u_mulder doesn't want to post an answer, Stack lets you post your own answer. You could give kudos to them and quoting them in it. It could also be a community wiki answer; the choice is yours/theirs ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Aye I know ;) just didn't want to make a community wiki answer just yet, was waiting on him top post his own answer :P

Comment: @u_mulder *The floor is yours* ;-) ^